# How to retrieve Custom Category Attribute (Magento2 )

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom category attribute .The attribute is  showing in category section and the data is saved in database .I want to retrieve the value of the category attribute i need it in menu. (Magento 2).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are updating with that attribute .
For example if you want to rename the category name with your attribute , you can create a Plugin for override the category name , and adding the new category name in the form created.

In this case create this files in your module:

> app/code/Your/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category">
        <plugin name="PluginName" type="Your\Module\Plugin\AfterCategoryName" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Your/Module/Plugin/AfterCategoryName.php

```
   use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

   class AfterCategoryName
   {
    protected $categoryModel;

    /**
     * AfterCategoryName constructor.
     * @param CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategoryFactory $categoryFactory)
    {
        $this->categoryModel = $categoryFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryNew
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryNew, $result)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryModel->create();
        $category->load($categoryNew->getId());
        $newCategoryName = $category->getData('your_attribute');

        if (!empty($newCategoryName)) {
            return $newCategoryName;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    }
```

Comment: i have creted id attrubute because i want to give id on menu achor